# Why is copper a metal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, states-of-matter

**Context**: Solid state physics

**Question**: Can it be reasoned in the context of solid state physics (perhaps within the band theory of solids?) that copper is a metal ?

Comment: Copper has a half-filled outer s shell (1 electron). This means the Fermi surface of copper is in a band, so it's conducting.

Answer (score 4):

Many places, and especially in everyday life, metals are defined by examples and descriptions of their properties.

In physics(solid state physics) metals are defined by the Fermi level within an electronic band.

I do not see anything that makes copper special from other metals in this sense.